# Hibernate trunc in criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

My sql query

```
 SELECT count(1),trunc(D_O_I) FROM TableName
WHERE P_D IN (3) AND
D_O_I BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('01/31/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') group by trunc(D_O_I)
```

And my Hibernate code for  query is as below..

```
session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableName.class).setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
           .add(Projections.groupProperty("dteOfIss"), "dteOfIssResult").add(Projections.rowCount(), "count")).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(GroupedDateDTO.class));




   criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(P_D IN ('3'))"));

   if (reportsForm.getFromDate() != null && reportsForm.getToDate() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trunc(D_O_I) >= to_date('"+ utils.convertDateToString(reportsForm.getFromDate()) + "', 'MM/dd/yyyy')"));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trunc(D_O_I) <= to_date('"+ utils.convertDateToString(reportsForm.getToDate()) + "', 'MM/dd/yyyy')"));
    }
listResult = criteria.list();
```

How to add Trunc to dteofIss in hibernate code? i tried diffrent way's but i am unable to fetch.

Please Help

Comment: Why would use trunc() in this case? Would the results of the query be any different if you use the full date?

Comment: Yes, count will differ if i am using the trunc

Comment: I am pretty sure you express your criteria clauses like this:         criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("D_O_I >= to_date('"+ utils.convertDateToString(reportsForm.getFromDate()) + "', 'MM/dd/yyyy')"));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("D_O_I <= (to_date('"+ utils.convertDateToString(reportsForm.getToDate()) + "', 'MM/dd/yyyy') + 1)"));